# $k^x(z - y) + k^y(x - z) + k^z(y - x) \neq 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $k > 0, k \neq 1$, and $x,y,z$ distinct real numbers. Show that
$$k^x(z - y) + k^y(x - z) +k^z(y - x) \neq 0.$$

My progress: Assume the expression is equal to 0. Write this as 
$$(z - y)k^x + k^z(y - x) = k^y(z-x).$$

Divide by $k^y$ and obtain 
$$(z-y)k^{x-y} + (y-x)k^{z - y} = z - x.$$
If we set $a = x - y, b = z - y$ we get that $a,b \neq 0$ and we can write the expression as
$$b k^a - ak^b = b - a \iff b ( k^a - 1) = a(k^b - 1) \iff \frac{k^a - 1}{k^b - 1} = \frac{a}{b}.$$

At this point I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: $$b k^a - ak^b = b - a $$ certainly is true if $(k=1)$ or $(a=b)$ or $(a=0)$ or $(b=0)$

Comment: Yes, but the conditions rule out all of those cases.

Comment: That's exactly the point !

Comment: If you can show that there are no other solutions, you will have proved the statement.

Comment: Well of course, my question was pretty much how can i show that there are no other solutions.